# Grails Command object failed to bind numbers

Tags: grails, object, command

Hello everyone,
              I am a newbie to grails. I am passing field values from gsp to controller via command object. There is one field called mobile number on my gsp page.But when i am going to access it via command object,it gives me error as typeMismatch i.e. it doesn't convert value like 98xxxxxxxx from string to integer.In my command object,i have mentioned it as integer as

```
 Integer mobile;
```

My code on gsp is :

```
 <label for="mobile">Mobile</label>
 <input type="text" value="${cmd?.mobile}" title="" name="mobile" id="mobile" size="30" maxlength="10"/>
```

where cmd is my command object.

And code in controller :

```
def addInstitute={InstituteCommand cmd->
   Address address=new Address();
   address.mobile=cmd.mobile;
}
```

It gives me typeMismatch error.Also when i enter values like 1111111111,it saves it but when i enter actual mobile no. it gives me typeMismatch error.What to do with this scenario ?

Answer (score 6):

Thats because the Integer range of values is from -2147483648 to 2147483647, whereas your mobile number is greater than 9800000000 (10 digits). You are better off storing it as a String

```
String mobile;
```

This makes more sense since you will most probably not perform any number operations on the mobile number. It will also allow you to store non-digit phone codes like +, -